# predict_generator and class labels

Tags: python, keras

I am using ImageDataGenerator to generate new augmented images and  extract bottleneck features from pretrained model but most of the tutorial I see on keras 
samples same no of training samples as number of images in directory.

```
 train_generator  = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                train_path,
                target_size=image_size,
                shuffle = "false",
                class_mode='categorical',
                batch_size=1)

bottleneck_features_train = model.predict_generator(
    train_generator, 2* nb_train_samples // batch_size)
```

Suppose I want 2 times more images from the above code, how I can get the desired class labels for the features extracted from bottleneck layer which are stored in tuple **train_generator**.

shouldnt the code in [training_generator.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/58fd1f0589d33aeb33c4129cfedfb7737495efc0/keras/engine/training_generator.py)  at line 422

```
x, _ = generator_output
```

do something like this

```
 => x, y = generator_output
```

and return tuple  `[np.concatenate(out) for out in all_outs],y`  from predict_generator

i.e return the corresponding class labels along with the predicted features **all_outs** since there is no way to get the corresponding labels without running generator twice.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using predict, normally you simply don't want Y, because Y will be the result of the prediction. (You're not training, so you don't need the true labels)

But you can do it yourself:

```py
bottleneck = []
labels = []
for i in range(2 * nb_train_samples // batch_size):
    x, y = next(train_generator)

    bottleneck.append(model.predict(x))
    labels.append(y) 

bottleneck = np.concatenate(bottleneck)
labels = np.concatenate(labels)
```

If you want it with indexing (if your generator supports that):

```py
#...
for epoch in range(2):
    for i in range(nb_train_samples // batch_size):
        x,y = train_generator[i]

        #...
```

Comment: Thanks. If we iterate two times no of images then will it create exactly two sampled image for every image of directory.

Comment: Yes it will. But if you're not using any kind of augmentation, why don't you simply use `epochs=more_epochs` when you start to use the bottlenecks?

Comment: Another question about shifting. why does tx work with height.

 tx = np.random.uniform(-hrg, hrg) * h

 ty = np.random.uniform(-wrg, wrg) * w