# Keras: Predicting New Values using predict_generator

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, prediction

At the moment I'm trying to follow a example of Temperature Forecasting in Keras (as given in chapter 6.3 of F. Chollet's "Deep Learning with Python" book). I'm having some issues with prediction using the generator that is specified. My understanding is that I should be using `model.predict_generator` for prediction, but I'm unsure how to use the `steps` parameter for this method and how to get back predictions that are the correct "shape" for my original data.

Ideally, I would like to be able to plot the test set (indices 300001 until the end) and also plot my predictions for this test set (i.e. an array of the same length with predicted values).

An example (Dataset available here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/keras-datasets/jena_climate_2009_2016.csv.zip) is as follows:

```py
import numpy as np

# Read in data
fname = ('jena_climate_2009_2016.csv')
f = open(fname)
data = f.read()
f.close()
lines = data.split('\n')
col_names = lines[0].split(',')
col_names = [i.replace('"', "") for i in col_names]

# Normalize the data
float_data = np.array(df.iloc[:, 1:])
temp = float_data[:, 1]
mean = float_data[:200000].mean(axis=0)
float_data -= mean
std = float_data[:200000].std(axis=0)
float_data /= std

def generator(data, lookback, delay, min_index, max_index, shuffle=False, batch_size=128, step=6):
    if max_index is None:
        max_index = len(data) - delay - 1
    i = min_index + lookback
    while 1:
        if shuffle:
            rows = np.random.randint(
                min_index + lookback, max_index, size=batch_size)
        else:
            if i + batch_size >= max_index:
                i = min_index + lookback
            rows = np.arange(i, min(i + batch_size, max_index))
            i += len(rows)
        samples = np.zeros((len(rows), 
                            lookback // step,
                            data.shape[-1]))
        targets = np.zeros((len(rows),))
        for j, row in enumerate(rows):
            indices = range(rows[j] - lookback, rows[j], step)
            samples[j] = data[indices]
            targets[j] = data[rows[j] + delay][1]
        yield(samples, targets)

lookback = 720
step = 6
delay = 144

train_gen = generator(float_data, lookback=lookback, delay=delay, 
                      min_index=0, max_index=200000, shuffle=True,
                      step=step, batch_size=batch_size)

val_gen = generator(float_data, lookback=lookback, delay=delay, 
                    min_index=200001, max_index=300000, step=step,
                    batch_size=batch_size)

test_gen = generator(float_data, lookback=lookback, delay=delay, 
                     min_index=300001, max_index=None, step=step, 
                     batch_size=batch_size)

val_steps = (300000 - 200001 - lookback)
test_steps = (len(float_data) - 300001 - lookback)

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras import layers
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop

model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Flatten(input_shape=(lookback // step, float_data.shape[-1])))
model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(), loss='mae')
model.fit_generator(train_gen, steps_per_epoch=500,
                              epochs=20, validation_data=val_gen,
                              validation_steps=val_steps)
```

After some searching around online, I tried some techniques similar to the following:

```
pred = model.predict_generator(test_gen, steps=test_steps // batch_size)
```

However the prediction array that I got back was far too long and didn't match up to my original data at all. Has anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I arrived at a semi-acceptable version of an answer to my own question, I decided to post it for posterity:

```
test_gen = generator(float_data, lookback=lookback, delay=delay, 
                     min_index=300001, max_index=None, step=step, 
                     batch_size=1)    # "reset" the generator

pred = model.predict_generator(test_gen, steps=test_steps)
```

This now has the shape I want to plot it against my original test set. I could also use a more manual approach inspired somewhat by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50586848/3763302):

```
test_gen = generator(float_data, lookback=lookback, delay=delay, 
                     min_index=300001, max_index=None, step=step, 
                     batch_size=1)    # "reset" the generator

truth = []
pred = []

for i in range(test_steps):
    x, y = next(test_gen)
    pred.append(model.pred(x))
    truth.append(y) 

pred = np.concatenate(pred)
truth = np.concatenate(truth)
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking at the question now, we are not required to specify the steps parameter when using `predict_generator` for the newer versions of keras. Ref: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11902

If a value is provided, predictions for `step*batch_size` examples will be generated. This may result in exclusion of `len(test)%batch_size` rows, as mentioned by OP.
Also, it seems to me that setting `batch_size=1` defeats the purpose of using the generator, as it is equivalent to iterating over the test data one by one.
Similarly setting `steps=1` (when `batch_size` is not set in `test_generator`) will read the entire test data at once, which is not ideal for large test data.

Answer (score 0):

In `predict_generator` for `steps` divide number of images you have in test path with whatever batchsize you have provided in `test_gen`
EX: i have `50` images and i provided batch size of `10` than steps would be `5`

```
#first seperate the `test images` and `test labels`
 test_images,test_labels = next(test_gen)

#get the class indices
 test_labels = test_labels[:,0]  #this should give you array of labels

predictions = model.predict_generator(test_gen,steps = number of images/batchsize,verbose=0)

predictions[:,0]  #this is your actual predictions
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately for the data set that I'm trying to use, it's not image data but a timeseries. If I try to separate into `data` and `labels` like what you have above, then my `labels` array will have a shape of `(128,)`, i.e. the same as the `batch_size`. Then of course I won't be able to use your next line of code to get the class indices as the shapes don't match up

Answer (score 0):

Your original code looks correct:

```
pred = model.predict_generator(test_gen, steps=test_steps // batch_size)
```

I tried and did not see any problem generating a `pred` of length around 120k. What size did you get?

Actually both of the steps in the code are incorrect. They should be:

```
val_steps = (300000 - 200001 - lookback) // batch_size
test_steps = (len(float_data) - 300001 - lookback) // batch_size
```

(Didn't it take forever for your validation to run for each epoch?)

Of course with this correction you can simply use

```
pred = model.predict_generator(test_gen, steps=test_steps)
```

Comment: `val_steps` and `test_steps` I took directly from the book mentioned (pg 212), and neither are divided by `batch_size`. My validation did indeed take forever to run for each epoch, yes! My `pred` was then of length `test_steps - (test_steps % batch_size)`, i.e. 119808. My problem was that I would have expected `pred` to be the same length as the original `test` set, which was 120550 (`float_data.shape[0] - 300001`). Now, if I plot predicted values and original values, do both of these arrays start at the same position?

Comment: Or, better still, how could I make my prediction array match up exactly to the test set?

Comment: First of all, I think the omission of the batch_size division is an error or oversight by the author. When using generators, the steps (`steps_per_epoch`, `validation_steps` and `steps`) should be the number of batches. Without the division, we are simply feeding extra data for fit, validation or prediction. That's why I asked if your validation runs forever (it's running 127 times more than necessary. Good that the generator function circles back so the index doesn't go out of bounds).

Comment: Your other question about how to align the data. Since we are using `lookback=720` and `delay=144`, the sample span from the earliest input data to the target or prediction should be `720+144=864`. That means your `pred` would be 864 samples shorter than the test data.

To match them, `pred[0]` should match with `test_data[864]` and so on.

Comment: The current implementation generates 128 sample every time the generator is called, so `pred` is even shorter than that. But fit_generator doesn't have to be that way. Note that when you fun `fit`, you can set `batch_size`, but that option is gone with `fit_generator`, because `fit_generator` takes whatever size that is yielded. So if you really want to get the last batch (with size<128) to work, you need to modify the `generator` function to handle it

Comment: Thanks for your comments, it's a big help. In terms of, as you mentioned, modifying the `generator` function to handle my exact test data size, doesn't my `generator` function in my answer here do that, with `batch_size=1`?

Comment: Yes it does, but it now generates 1-sample batches that would be very slow. What I meant was to modify the generator (it should not be difficult) to output, say, 128 samples per batch, but at the end also output the remaining, say, 25 samples.